# JSF JBWEB006017 Target Unreachable when a column (composition) is used in a table (composite)

Tags: jsf, datatable, composition, composite-component

We are currently working on creating "standard" JSF components for our current and future projects. One of the components is a table where columns can easily be added.

The **table.xhtml** is a composite components and looks like this:

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="dataModel" required="true"
        type="com.my.jsf.model.BaseDataModel" />
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <div style="margin-bottom: 4px">
        <h:dataTable id="#{cc.clientId}"
            value="#{cc.attrs.dataModel.wrappedData}" var="entry" width="100%">

            <composite:insertChildren />

        </h:dataTable>
    </div>
</composite:implementation>
```

Then there will be a so called **dataColumn.xhtml** which is responsible for displaying and sorting data ...

```
<ui:composition ...>

    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:panelGroup
                style="float: left; font-weight: 600; font-size: 1.2em; padding-left: 4px;">
                <h:commandLink value="#{title}"
                    action="#{cc.attrs.dataModel.sort(sortKey)}"
                    rendered="#{!(empty sortKey)}" />

                <h:outputText value="#{title}" rendered="#{empty sortKey}" />

                <c:if test="#{cc.attrs.dataModel.isSortOrderAsc(sortKey)}">
                    <i class="fa fa-sort-alpha-asc" />
                </c:if>

                <c:if test="#{cc.attrs.dataModel.isSortOrderDesc(sortKey)}">
                    <i class="fa fa-sort-alpha-desc" />
                </c:if>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </f:facet>

        <h:panelGroup>
            <h:outputText value="#{value}"
                style="font-size: 1.2em; padding-left: 4px;" />
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:column>
</ui:composition>
```

... and additionally a selectionColumn.xhtml which allows the selection of a row:

```
<ui:composition ...>

    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="selectAll" value="false"
                onclick="selectAll(this, 'selected#{id}Row');" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:panelGroup style="display:block; text-align:center">
                <h:selectBooleanCheckbox
                    value="#{cc.atts.dataModel.checkedItems[identifier]}"
                    id="selected#{id}Row" />
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:column>

</ui:composition>
```

Finally when the composite components and compositions are put together, the whole thing looks like this:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    ...
    template="/layout/layoutoriginal.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form id="createForm">
            <div class="form_module">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Sample</legend>

                    <my:table dataModel="#{pageNavigationController.dataModel}">
                        <my:dataColumn title="Firstname" value="#{entry.firstname}" sortKey="FIRSTNAME" />
                        <my:dataColumn title="Lastname" value="#{entry.lastname}" sortKey="LASTNAME" />
                        <my:selectionColumn identifier="#{entry.id}" />
                    </my:table>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

When the **selectionColumn** is added to the **table** then i receive an exception which states:

```
value="#{cc.attrs.dataModel.checkedItems[identifier]}": JBWEB006017: Target Unreachable, ''dataModel'' returned null
        at javax.faces.component.UIInput.updateModel(UIInput.java:857) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.29.Final.jar:2.1.29.Final]
        at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processUpdates(UIInput.java:739) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.29.Final.jar:2.1.29.Final]
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1244) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.29.Final.jar:2.1.29.Final]
        at javax.faces.component.UIData.iterate(UIData.java:2013) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.29.Final.jar:2.1.29.Final]
        at javax.faces.component.UIData.processUpdates(UIData.java:1266) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.29.Final.jar:2.1.29.Final]
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1244) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.29.Final.jar:2.1.29.Final]
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1244) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.29.Final.jar:2.1.29.Final]
        at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processUpdates(UIForm.java:281) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.29.Final.jar:2.1.29.Final]
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1244) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.29.Final.jar:2.1.29.Final]
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1244) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.29.Final.jar:2.1.29.Final]
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1244) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.29.Final.jar:2.1.29.Final]
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1244) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.29.Final.jar:2.1.29.Final]
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processUpdates(UIViewRoot.java:1223) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.29.Final.jar:2.1.29.Final]
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.UpdateModelValuesPhase.execute(UpdateModelValuesPhase.java:78) [jsf-impl-2.1.29.jar:2.1.29]
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.29.jar:2.1.29]
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118) [jsf-impl-2.1.29.jar:2.1.29]
    ...
```

This somehow irritates me as the **dataColumn** is working just fine and also utilizes the **cc.attrs.dataModel >BUT<** inside the header. For the **selectionColumn**, I need the value inside the column, not in the header. So is this part of the problem and if so, is there a workaround without the need to pass the **dataModel** in the **selectionColumn**?

P.S.: Because of the working **dataColumn** I does not added any backing bean code as I assume that the failure is not found in the backing bean ... it must be some kind of JSF lifecycle problem?

**UPDATE 1:**
A possible but not very elegant workaround: define dataModel as a attribute in **selectionColumn.xhtml**

```
...
            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox
                value="#{cc.attrs.dataModel.checkedItems[identifier]}"
                id="selected#{id}Row" />
...
```

and pass the data model to the

```
            <my:table dataModel="#{pageNavigationController.dataModel}">
                <my:dataColumn title="Firstname" value="#{entry.firstname}" sortKey="FIRSTNAME" />
                <my:dataColumn title="Lastname" value="#{entry.lastname}" sortKey="LASTNAME" />
                <my:selectionColumn identifier="#{entry.id}" dataModel="#{pageNavigationController.dataModel}"/>
            </my:table>
```

I am not very happy with this workaround because the **dataColumn** already utilizes the **cc.attrs.dataModel** ... I would appreciate alternative workarounds/solutions.

Comment: Your JSF API/impl versions don't match as per your stacktrace. Although I don't think that this is the cause. Interesting use case btw, are you saying that `<my:dataColumn>` alone works fine? I once tried this construct in some Mojarra 2.0.x version, but it failed hard because `UIData` only accepted `UIColumn` children not `UIPanel` from composites. I should try it with current versions again.

Comment: Hi @BalusC ... yes, `<my:dataColumn>` is working but only as `<ui:composition>` not as `<composite:implementation>` ... I have not found an identical approach where compositions are included in a composite component ... maybe this approach isn't supposed to work? Regarding API/impl: thanks for the hint ... we are only allowed to utilize JSF 2.1, per company policy 2.1.19.1. I updated my jboss locally to see if this changes anything but forgot to update the impl.

Comment: @BalusC ... updated modules to match API with impl. As you stated it does not solves the problem ... also updated question with working (but not optimal) solution to this problem.